# Deleting element from Xml breaks format on reload

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-serialization

I am creating a system that stores vehicle data. When I serialize the data using Xml serialization, I get the correct format as shown in the example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<ArrayOfVehicle xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <Vehicle>
    <Registration>fake1</Registration>
    <Model>123</Model>
    <Make>test</Make>
    <Year>1999</Year>
    <Cost>100</Cost>
  </Vehicle>

  <Vehicle>
    <Registration>fake2</Registration>
    <Model>321</Model>
    <Make>123</Make>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Cost>321</Cost>
  </Vehicle>

</ArrayOfVehicle>
```

The serialization uses a list of vehicles that have the attributes seen in the Xml file. I am trying to figure out how I can delete a vehicle from the list and serialize it back to the Xml file without breaking the format shown above.

The method that I have tried to use to delete the records from the list and serialize and deserialize the data, but when I remove and item, it breaks the format. This is what the Xml file looks like when I remove an item from the list and serialize it:

`fake1 123 test 1999 100`

Here is my code for removing an item:

```
                for (int i = Business.VehicleList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                { //Where Business.VehicleList is my list
                    if (Business.VehicleList[i].Registration == registration)
                    {
                        Business.VehicleList.RemoveAt(i);
                        Business.Save(); //Method for serialization
                    }
                }
```

Here is the error it throws when I try to deserialize the data again:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (10, 19). XmlException: There are multiple root elements. Line 10, position 19.'`

These are my serialization and deserialization methods:

```
    public static void Retrieve()
    {
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\data.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                if (fileStream.Length <= 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Vehicle>),
                    new XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfVehicle"));
                    _vehicleList = (List<Vehicle>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader); //This is where the error is thrown
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Save()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Vehicle>));
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\data.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(fileStream, VehicleList);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to remove a vehicle from my list without it breaking the Xml file?

Here is the source after I tried deleting an item from the vehicle string

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfVehicle xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Vehicle>
    <Registration>123</Registration>
    <Model>123</Model>
    <Make>23</Make>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Cost>123</Cost>
  </Vehicle>
</ArrayOfVehicle><Registration>1321</Registration>
    <Model>123123</Model>
    <Make>312312</Make>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Cost>321</Cost>
  </Vehicle>
</ArrayOfVehicle>
```

Comment: The file content you mention ("fake1 123 test 1999 100") does not match the error message as this is not even XML.

Comment: Thats what I mean. When I create the instances of the vehicle and serialize it, it looks like the Xml format example. But when I delete an item from the list and serialize it, it removes the XML format and serializes as `"fake1 123 test 1999 100"`

Comment: There is no way an XmlSerializer could produce this output. Unfortunately your code is incomplete and cannot be compiled. It would be good if you supply a [mre].

Comment: I dont really know how to respond to this. What Ive said is what is happening. Ive also tested a foreach statement that checks each item in the list. if that item exists, I remove it from the list and serialize it. This still breaks the Xml format and displays it as a string format rather than the Xml format. Im not sure as to why it does it, but it is doing it.

Comment: I can add additional things like my classes if that helps, like vehicle class etc, but it wouldn't really help with the situation

Answer (score 1):

In the Save method, `new FileStream("C:\\temp\\data.xml", FileMode.Open)` will open the existing file without truncating it. So after you write the new XML data to the file, there will be remnants of the old content if the new content is shorter than the old one.

Changing this to `new FileStream("C:\\temp\\data.xml", FileMode.Create)` will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are trying to de-serialize a malformed xml. Please first, make sure that your serialization method produces correct xml. The reason may be because of closing the stream inside `using` statement. And also serializing the list before `for-loop` finishes.

Try removing `fileStream.Close();` and also moving `Business.Save();` to outside of `for-loop`.

Here, I made a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oIzdjg) with same conditions and it works.

Comment: I found that when I open the XML file in my browser after deleting all of the items from the list, it displays no code. But if I inspect the source, it still contains the data, but the format has changed slightly. It shifts vehicle into the previous line like this `<ArrayOfVehicle xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />  <Vehicle>`

Comment: Can you open it with a text editor and paste results here so we can see the difference

Comment: Ill add it to the bottom of the question

Comment: It seams to have removed the <Vehicle> and not the </Vehicle>, and shifted it outside the root

Comment: Ok, i see, please try my recommendations and paste resulting xml again